# how to update accept/reject of table of db in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i created an appointments table where user1 would add appointments and user2 would accept/reject the appointment. **now my problem is when the accept and reject are clicked it is displayed in the table but it is not updated in  the db** I've did a lot of research over this but hit a road block after road block, so I really hope your help in this, many thanks!

Here is an image of my appointments table:
[image: app (apportionment db)]

Here is my code:

```
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example"> 
                    <thead>
                          <tr>
                                <th>appoinment ID</th>
                              <th>Date</th>
                                <th>time</th>
                              <th>teacher</th>
                             <th>parent</th>
                              <th> accept/reject </th>
                              <th>state</th>
                            </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                        <?php 
                            $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `app` left join `par` on par.par_id=app.par_id
                            left join `tea` on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id
                            ORDER BY app_id DESC");

                                if($query === false)
                                {
                                    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($conn));
                                }
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                {
                                    $ann_id=$row['app_id'];
                                    $date=$row['date'];
                                    $msg=$row['time'];

                                    $username = $row['username'];
                                     $username = $row['p_username'];
                        ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['app_id'] ?></td>
                     <td> <?php echo date('j/m/y',strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['time'] ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>

                    <td>
        <a href="#" class="reject">reject</a> 
        <a href="#" class="accept">accept</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="chgtext">PENDING</div>
    </td>

                </tr>

                        <?php   

    if (isset($_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id'])) {
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET state = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $_GET['state'], $_GET['s.app_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}

                                 }

                       ?>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
         </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: What is the name of your php page?

Comment: @ZainFarooq tea_appview.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error there. You are using `$_GET` request with setting it in url. Change your html tag like below

```
 <a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=reject";?>" class="reject">reject</a>

<a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=accept";?>" class="reject">accept</a> <!-- I assumed that column names in database were app_id and state
```

And in php code

```
if (isset($_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id'])) {
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET state = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}

}
```

I hope it will help you. If there is any problem then kindly tell me

Comment: i need to display pending by default & when accept/reject is clicked it must be converted

Comment: Great! It pleasure

Comment: Converted means here?

Comment: You can add a column in database of `pending`. If you ever click on `accept/reject` then you should updated pending column to some value

Comment: For example if `pending` value is `1` then you should not display it and if it is `0` then you should display it.

Comment: when i add appointments i added a hidden field with value PENDING then when accept/reject is clicked it would be updated...thanks bro

Comment: `$query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from app left join par on par.par_id=app.par_id left join tea on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id ORDER BY app_id ASC");` **i need to filter the data where the tea_id is the session user i tried to do it but it doesn`t work  can u pls help**